# Timeline component for displaying profiling data

Tags: user-interface, charts, profiling, timeline

I'm looking to display some data in a timeline format that most profilers are using:

- [Unity Profiler](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2012/12/07/three-ninja-camp-vii-projects-at-a-glimpse/profilertimeline/)
- [nVidia Visual Profiler](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2013/09/no_nvtx.png)
- [Google Chrome Flamechart](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/revolutions2013/?redirect_from_locale=de#toc-flame-chart)

But I cannot find a good framework to create such graphs by myself. I'm not looking for a specific language or GUI framework, but C++ or Python would be preferred.

The solution should be open source and portable (Linux and Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed in Chromes [trace-viewer](https://code.google.com/p/trace-viewer/).